# Finding a maximal convex figure in a closed polygon

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $C$ be a closed polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I would like to find a maximal convex figure contained in $C$. "Maximal" means that it is not contained in any other convex figure contained in $C$ (it does not need to have maximum area).

I know how to find a maximal *axes-parallel rectangle* contained in $C$: just start from an arbitrary point inside $C$, and stretch it to the right and left and top and bottom, until it bumps into the boundary of $C$. This process is well-defined since $C$ is closed (contains its boundary).

But, finding a maximal *convex figure* seems more complicated since there are infinitely many directions to stretch...

Comment: *Any* maximal convex figure? It's not going to be unique in general. Take for example a square $ABCD$ with center $O$ and consider the non-convex pentagon $ABOCD\,$, then both $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$ are "*maximal*".

Comment: @dxiv yes, I know it will not be unique... I only need one.

Comment: That's why it is called **maximal** not maximum @dxiv

Comment: Same example as before, take any $P$ on $AB$ and let $Q = PO \cap CD\,$, then $APQD$ will be maximal. I believe the idea generalizes to arbitrary polygons: determine the convex hull, pick a vertex of the original polygon which is strictly *inside* the convex hull, then draw an arbitrary line through it which runs inside the polygon in a neighborhood of said vertex. Take the intersections of that line with the other sides of the polygon, and consider that to be the next polygon, then repeat until you get a convex figure. Of course, this would need quite some formalizing before becoming a proof.

Comment: Is your polygon simple?

Comment: @Ashkan: That might be really difficult also for simple polygons. If the starting polygon is, literally, a maze, it is not trivial to understand from which point it is best to start expanding, or from which vertex it is best to start cutting.

Comment: For instance, it is quite difficult to find the largest enclosed convex set in this polygon: http://i.imgur.com/GlfzttG.png

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  No matter what point on (or inside) Polygon you start to expanding , your maximal expansion (which is attained by Zorn lemma) is always the answer of problem. 

The good thing about  polygon (considering its inside too) can be  written is finite union of maximal convex sets (lets call them convex components) and each component gives you an answer.

Comment: @Ashkan: of course, but with a computational point of view *a solution exists by Zorn's lemma* is often not enough to find a solution efficiently.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio   (computation)  That's  exactly the reason I pointed out we need more arguments, Like simple polygon, to introduce an Algorithm! the order of Computation depends on the structure of problem, when a problem is given in general setting without specification, I think we shouldn't expect efficient algorithm ! In simple polygon, picking any vertex , there are only two extreme directions, traveling along those direction we probably can find one convex component!

Comment: @Ashkan: I do not agree: take a regular polygon with a great number of sides and add to it a large amount of extremely thin tentacles: the solution to the given problem for simple polygons might have nothing to do with the vertices of the original polygon, or they might be as many as the elements of $\mathbb{N}$, so to try every vertex is not really a computational chance.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  I didn't get exactly your example, but anyway you introduced an example in which the computation is time-consuming if we start from an arbitrarily vertex. OK That's the price to pay! For any algorithm you can construct a pathological example. You are claiming we should start an specific vertex!  In same example you mentioned you added many vertex too!  so any criteria to identify a good vertex is time consuming as well. Look at best optimization algorithms on polyhedral, in the world, all start from an arbitrary vertex, Like simplex algorithm and interior point!

Comment: @Ashkan Is it true that (a) any polygon can be composed to a finite number of convex components and (b) any such convex component is a maximal contained convex figure?

Comment: Yes, See my suggested answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be an solid polygon (polygon $\cup$ inside): Pick $x \in P$ and Define $$ \Gamma=\{ A \subseteq P ~| ~x\in A , ~ A \text{ is nonempty convex}  \} $$  Then the set $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$ since $\{x\}  \in  \Gamma$ and it is partially ordered under inclusion $(\subseteq).$ Now picking any chain in $\Gamma$, say $\{A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I},$ one can show that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}  \in \Gamma $. So $\{A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I},$ has an upper bound in $\Gamma,$ and therefore Zorn lemma guarantees $\Gamma$ has a maximal element, say $M$,   it is actually a maximal convex subset of $P$ containing $x.$ 
Thus you pick $x \in P$ and start convex expansion to get one maximal convex subset. (It is always possible based above argument!)

Note that Since $P$ is bounded this expansion is bounded, you finally stop somewhere in convex expansion process. And since Polygon has a finitely many extreme points, the number of such maximal convex components is finite .

Comment: Does your proof use the assumption that the polygon $P$ is closed? Maybe it is used in the claim that the union of each chain in $\Gamma$ is an element of $\Gamma$? I am not sure it is needed.

Comment: By Polygon I already meant , it is a closed polygon (as it is defined :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon).   Other wise the inside of polygon is not defined !

Comment: What if $P$ is the interior of a polygon without its boundary, i.e, it is an open set?

Comment: Yes, but why is it important for you?

Comment: Initially, I thought that the claim is only true when $P$ is closed, since in general, only closed sets are guaranteed to have maxima. Now, your beautiful proof apparently does not use closedness, so I want to understand whether closedness is needed or not.

Comment: Also, by what name can I cite your answer?

Comment: See Lemma 3.3 in this paper  https://128.84.21.199/abs/1704.06932v1
@ErelSegal-Halevi

Comment: Actually I didn't get , what you meant by name!   You can call this lemma the convex components of polygons  @ErelSegal-Halevi

Comment: I meant to ask about your name. I see it now in the paper. Thanks!